# FastAPI post form params with guzzle in laravel not working but works on curl and postman

Tags: python, php, laravel, tensorflow, fastapi

I am trying to build a fastapi service for vector embeddings using the universal sentence encoder model, the api works well when queried with postman or on curl. but when I make a form post from Guzzle, I get a 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

Here is my schema.py file.

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Form, status, Request
from absl import logging
from typing import List, Annotated
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

import tensorflow as tf

import tensorflow_hub as hub
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import re
import seaborn as sns
import pickle
import json

# Disable tensorflow msg about AVX, AVX2 and FMA ..
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'



app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    exc_str = f'{exc}'.replace('\n', ' ').replace('   ', ' ')
    logging.error(f"{request}: {exc_str}")
    content = {'status_code': 10422, 'message': exc_str, 'data': None}
    return JSONResponse(content=content, status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)


@app.get('/', status_code=200)
async def index():
    return {"message": "Welcome to AutoML"}

@app.post("/embed", status_code=200)
def embed_content(input: List = Form(...)):
    print("Data input is as follows")
    print(input)
    # input =list(input)
    module_file = "./src/models/" #@param ["https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4", "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"]
    model = hub.load(module_file)
    # print ("module %s loaded" % module_file)
    embeddings = model(input)
    df = pd.DataFrame(input, columns = ['input'])
    # print(df)

    df['embedding'] = list(tf.keras.backend.eval(embeddings))
    # print(df)
    return {"data" : parse_csv(df)}
    # return {"q": input}


def parse_csv(df):
    res = df.to_json(orient="records")
    parsed = json.loads(res)
    return parsed


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run("main:app", host="127.0.0.1",port=8000, reload=True)
```

This works as expected on curl and postman.
the following php code in laravel using Guzzle however returns an error.

```
     public function getQueryEmbedding($content): array | bool
    {

        try {

            $client = new Client([
                'base_uri' => 'http://lendsignals.app:8000',
                'timeout' => 0,
                'allow_redirects' => false,
            ]);
            $headers = [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ];

            $data = [
                "input" => $content,
            ];
            
            $response = $client->post("/embed", $headers,
                [
                    'form_params' => $data,
                ]            
            );

            if ($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {
                $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents, true);

                if (count($result['data']) == 0) {
                    throw new Exception("Failed to generated query embedding!");
                }

                return $result['data'][0]['embedding'];
                // return $result;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e) {
            // Todo: Catch errors here
            return false;
        }

    }
```

This is the error from uvicorn log when i make the guzzle request.

```
ERROR:absl:<starlette.requests.Request object at 0x000001E982AD8350>: [{'loc': ('body', 'input'), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]
INFO:     127.0.0.1:61550 - "POST /embed HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Thanks in advance.

Edits: Adding Postman and terminal (curl) screenshots

[image: Postman Request/Response Screenshot]

[image: Curl request/response]

[image: Uvicorn log from curl request]

Comment: What is `$content` in this case?

Comment: well you are running into a validation error, so check your $data

Comment: Sorry, I updated the PHP code to show $content with the rest of the function, actually $content is the text/content that I want to get the vector embeddings for

Comment: The body of the 422 error will have information about _which_ content is actually missing from your request (i.e. what was expected but wasn't included).

Comment: This is the body from the error {'loc': ('body', 'input'), 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}. even though the input is available,

Comment: @JeanLinux .may be content type should application json .   'Content-Type' => 'application/json',

Comment: 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' does not fix it, already tried that. FastAPI is a little different in my opinion.

Comment: better add postman screenshot

Comment: Just to check, your PHP code is running against `http://lendsignals.app`, while your postman/curl calls are to `localhost`, is that right?

Comment: yeah, lendsignals.app is my local domain .. points to 127.0.0.1